# Problem with showUserLocation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, core-location

am trying to show the user location in my mapView, but showUserLocation property only shows an annotation in "California" !! while am in Europe !!
I have put an NSLog to show the longitude and latitude and it logs -180.00.. for both, so i thaught may be that's the default user's location.
Am wondering if there some kind of permission to access gps or i don't know may be something else.

pleaaaase help am really stuck in here

Comment: Are you using the simulator? Simulator always use Cupertino as user location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the CoreLocation framework. It will give you the latitude and longitude coordinates of the device, you can then go to them on the map view.

Comment: My app is running in the simulator, may be that's the problem, is it?

Comment: Yeah, no doubt that's the problem. If you want to actually test it, try it out on an actual device.

Answer (score 0):

## import

## import

@interface RootViewController : UIViewController

{

CLLocationManager   *locationManager;

} 
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end

The implementation of our view controller is as follows:

## import "RootViewController.h"

#import

@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize locationManager;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
  {

NSLog(@"Latitude = %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude);

NSLog(@"Longitude = %f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude);